# Building a wordle with Python program output

Tags: python

My program generates a set of words from which I intend to build a [wordle](http://www.wordle.net/). I don't know how I can build the wordle part? How can I run this program on a server and then send the output to some website that generates wordles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a POST request to http://www.wordle.net/advanced with the parameter text set to the text you want.